# Openshift Route one host to two ports

Tags: routes, openshift

I have an application which requieres tls-client-authentication for all its routes except for one path, lets call it "/some-path".

Now I tried to setup two routes with the same host like:

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
name: route-path
spec:
  host: example.com
  path: "/some-path"
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: my-service
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: http
  tls:
    termination: edge 
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: None
---
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1 
kind: Route
name: route
spec:
  host: example.com
  path: ""
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: my-service
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: https
  tls:
    termination: passthrough 
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: None
```

The problem is, that I can't access the http port of my application, since the route "route" also catches the traffic for that path. Is there any solution to this except change the host or path of the rest of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried setting`path: "/"` in the second route?

Based on the ['Path-based routes'](https://docs.okd.io/latest/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-path-based-routes_route-configuration), it should work if you use the default ingress controler:

> Routers should match routes based on the most specific path to the least. However, this depends on the router implementation.

Also, as stated below in the doc, as you mix`"edge"`and`"passthrough"`TLS termination, I'm not sure it will work

> Path-based routing is not available when using passthrough TLS, as the router does not terminate TLS in that case and cannot read the contents of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Path specific Route: example.com/test

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: route-unsecured
spec:
  host: example.com
  path: "/test" 
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: service-name
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: route-unsecured
spec:
  host: example.com
  path: "/" 
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: service-name
```